# How restrict page for users logged?

Tags: pages

I have a website with login page that works normal. The problem is that once logged in, the user still has access to the login page form to enter, which should not happen.

I would like to know a wordpres plugin that redirects this user to another page when they access it after login.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, you'd be looking for [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/). You'd want to put this in your `header.php`, or on the page itself:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // user logged in, redirect
    // One way to redirect is: 
    // wp_redirect('http://YOURSITE.com/');
    exit();
} else {
    // user not logged in, nothing
}
```

Otherwise, if you're just looking for a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/